# How much of a gap in schach is acceptable?

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, sukkah, schach

How large of a gap is allowed in a sukkah's *schach* (roof) without invalidating it? (in *tefachim* and inches/feet, if possible)

Would it make a difference if the gap was in the middle of the roof, or on the side (=next to the wall) [דופן עקומה]?

> Related question: [How much invalid material invalidates schach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47339/5323)

Comment: QS"A Yalqut Yosef, Orahh Hayim 632:2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sukka 17a Mishnah:

> הרחיק את הסיכוך מן הדפנות שלשה טפחים פסולה בית שנפחת וסיכך על גביו אם יש מן הכותל לסיכוך ארבע אמות פסולה
>
> If the s'chach is distanced more than 3 handsbreadths from the walls then it is invalid.  If the roof caved, and you put schach into the breach, if there are more than 4 cubits from the wall then it is invalid.

If there is airspace, you have 3 handsbreadths. If there is invalid schach material, then you have 4 cubits from the wall.

S.A. 632:2

> אויר בין בגדולה בין בקטנה שוים דבין באמצע בין מן הצד בשלשה טפחים פסולה בפחות משלשה כשרה ומצטרף להשלים הסוכה ואין ישנים תחתיו
>
> Airspace, whether in the middle or on the side, invalidates at 3 tefachim.  At less than 3, it counts to complete the Sukkah but you shouldn't sleep under it.

Rama:

> ודוקא שהולך על פני כל הסוכה
>
> [It only cannot be slept under] if it spans the length of the Sukkah.

Comment: What about invalid material in the middle?

Comment: @DoubleAA It wasn't asked about so I didn't include it.  If anyone looks up my sources, it's the end of that same Rama - 4 tefachim.

Comment: But +1, nice answer. I like MY halacha answers that start at the mishna or gemara and end with SA/Rama -- gives a nice, complete picture.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47339/5323