# How much invalid material invalidates schach?

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, sukkah, schach

How much invalid material invalidates schach? <sub>(*tefachim* + inches preferred, but not required)</sub>

Would it make a difference if this material was in the middle of the roof, or on the side (=next to the wall)?

> Related question: [How much of a gap in schach is acceptable?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47298/5323)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 tefachim of invalid material invalidates schach.

S.A. O.C. 632:1

> סכך פסול פוסל באמצע בארבעה טפחים אבל פחות מארבעה כשרה ומותר לישן תחתיו מן הצד אינו פוסל אלא בארבע אמות
>
> Invalid schach invalidates in the middle of the sukkah at 4 tefachim, but at less than 4 you could even sleep under it.  At the side, you get up to 4 amos.